# Create a single for loop to calculate both the sum and product of all the numbers in the data

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I need to create a single `for-loops` and calculate the sum and product of all the numbers in the dataset (data1).
Here is my data:
[image: Data1]

Instead of getting the sum and products, my code only displays the list of data. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code so far:

```
s.total <- 0
p.total <- 1

for(j in data1) {
  s.total <- s.total + j
  p.total <- p.total * j
}
s.total
p.total
```

Incorrect output:

```
> s.total
 [1] 1.3 1.7 1.2 1.6 1.5 1.9 1.4 1.5 1.8 1.3
> p.total
 [1] 1.3 1.7 1.2 1.6 1.5 1.9 1.4 1.5 1.8 1.3
```

Correct answers should be `15.20` for `sum` and `59.42559` for `product`

Comment: Check out the `sum` and `prod` functions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: No, because we haven't covered `function` yet in class. We were instructed to just use basic `for-loops`

Comment: Should I just add these after the closing bracket?
`sum(s.total)`
`prod(p.total)`

Comment: Quit R. Restart. Type: `data1 <- c(1, 3, 7)`. Then run your code. You should get 11 and 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over values of the column. Right now you are looping over the entire dataframe.

Assuming the column is called `col`, using `for` loop, you can do :

```
data1 <- data.frame(col = c(1.3, 2.4, 3.5))
s.total <- 0
p.total <- 1


for(j in data1$col) {
  s.total <- s.total + j
  p.total <- p.total * j
}

s.total
#[1] 7.2
p.total
#[1] 10.92
```

which gives the same value using `sum` and `prod`

```
sum(data1$col)
#[1] 7.2
prod(data1$col)
#[1] 10.92
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been working on this for hours! I just realized that the dataset already has a column name so I just have to add the `data1$col`. It worked!!